# when does componentResized get called?

Tags: java, debugging, components, componentlistener

hello i'm new to java programming and when does a componentResized get called? does it get called when your program first starts up? because in my code and i didn't add the "rect" in the center of the screen, until the window got resized. but whenever i start my program, the "rect" is added to the middle of the screen. i'm sorry if i sound vague but thank u so much for taking a look at this. hope u have a great day!

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import acm.graphics.GCanvas;
import acm.graphics.GRect;

public class MyCanvas extends GCanvas implements ComponentListener {

    public MyCanvas() {
        addComponentListener(this);
        rect = new GRect(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        rect.setFilled(true);
    }

    public void update() {
        removeAll();
        add(rect, (getWidth() - WIDTH) / 2, (getHeight() - HEIGHT) / 2);
    }

    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        add(rect, 20, 20);
        update();
    }

    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}

    private int WIDTH = 30;
    private int HEIGHT = 30;

    private GRect rect;
}
```

Comment: According to the JavaDoc it is "Invoked when the component's size changes.". That means when the window gets layed out this should be called, unless you didn't register the listener.

Comment: thank you so much tomas. it really helped